# div Resizing with inner content and maintain aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

I have made a code pen example for complete understanding please checkout this link
https://codepen.io/hasan-irshad/pen/bGpPZzB

this is the code which i am using for bottom right corner

```
if (currentResizer.classList.contains('bottom-right')) {
    const width = original_width + (e.pageX - original_mouse_x);
    const height = original_height + (e.pageY - original_mouse_y)
    if (width > minimum_size) {
      element.style.width = width + 'px'
      element.style.height = 'max-content';
      let Textdiv = document.getElementById('Text');
      let relFontsizew = Textdiv.offsetWidth * 0.25;
      Textdiv.style.fontSize = relFontsizew + 'px';
    }
  }
```

if you resize div from bottom right corner it works fine as I want it to work, from bottom right corner it increases/decreases width of div according to the mouse-X, and height of div according to the inner content height. This is the behavior which I want to implement on all the corners.

for example if I drag from bottom right corner so the top left corner stays at it's position
just like that if I resize it from top right corner so bottom left corner should maintain it's position.

expected behavior
1 width of outer element should depend on mouse-X
2 font size should be dependent on width of outer div
3 height of outer div should depend on inner content height
4 div element should not lose its position

below is a link of video for demonstration of end result which I want to implement.
drive.google.com/file/d/1Wgh3GhEOhv1syk_WFmcCGp0UJUyGzS5u/view

can anybody please help me complete this task?

Thanks a lot in advance!!!!!

Comment: Please re-read your question, there are several ambiguous sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I comment the things out you dont need, and inserted the things you should add, it was mainly that you dont need to set the realtive position and you needed to set the height to "max-content", and the only time you add a script to change your font-size was in the right-bottom corner.

```
          let Textdiv = document.getElementById('Text');
          let relFontsizew = Textdiv.offsetWidth * 0.25;
          Textdiv.style.fontSize = relFontsizew + 'px';
```

```js
/*Make resizable div by Hung Nguyen*/


function makeResizableDiv(div) {
  const element = document.querySelector(div);
  const resizers = document.querySelectorAll(div + ' .resizer')
  const minimum_size = 20;
  let original_width = 0;
  let original_height = 0;
  let original_x = 0;
  let original_y = 0;
  let original_mouse_x = 0;
  let original_mouse_y = 0;
  for (let i = 0;i < resizers.length; i++) {
    const currentResizer = resizers[i];
    currentResizer.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      original_width = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('width').replace('px', ''));
      original_height = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('height').replace('px', ''));
      original_x = element.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      original_y = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      original_mouse_x = e.pageX;
      original_mouse_y = e.pageY;
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', resize)
      window.addEventListener('mouseup', stopResize)
    })
    
    function resize(e) {
      if (currentResizer.classList.contains('bottom-right')) {
        const width = original_width + (e.pageX - original_mouse_x);
        const height = original_height + (e.pageY - original_mouse_y)
        if (width > minimum_size) {
          element.style.width = width + 'px'
          element.style.height = 'max-content';
          let Textdiv = document.getElementById('Text');
          let relFontsizew = Textdiv.offsetWidth * 0.25;
          Textdiv.style.fontSize = relFontsizew + 'px';
        }
      }
      else if (currentResizer.classList.contains('bottom-left')) {
        const height = original_height + (e.pageY - original_mouse_y)
        const width = original_width - (e.pageX - original_mouse_x)
        if (height > minimum_size) {
          element.style.height = "max-content"
        }
        if (width > minimum_size) {
          element.style.width = width + 'px'
          element.style.left = original_x + (e.pageX - original_mouse_x) + 'px'
          let Textdiv = document.getElementById('Text');
          let relFontsizew = Textdiv.offsetWidth * 0.25;
          Textdiv.style.fontSize = relFontsizew + 'px';
        }
      }
      else if (currentResizer.classList.contains('top-right')) {
        const width = original_width + (e.pageX - original_mouse_x)
        const height = original_height - (e.pageY - original_mouse_y)
        if (width > minimum_size) {
          element.style.width = width + 'px'
          element.style.height = "max-content"
          //element.style.top = original_y + (e.pageY - original_mouse_y) + 'px'
          let Textdiv = document.getElementById('Text');
          let relFontsizew = Textdiv.offsetWidth * 0.25;
          Textdiv.style.fontSize = relFontsizew + 'px';
        }
      }
      else {
        const width = original_width - (e.pageX - original_mouse_x)
        const height = original_height - (e.pageY - original_mouse_y)
        if (width > minimum_size) {
          element.style.width = width + 'px'
          element.style.left = original_x + (e.pageX - original_mouse_x) + 'px'
        }
        if (height > minimum_size) {
          element.style.height = "max-content"
          //element.style.top = original_y + (e.pageY - original_mouse_y) + 'px'
        }
         let Textdiv = document.getElementById('Text');
          let relFontsizew = Textdiv.offsetWidth * 0.25;
          Textdiv.style.fontSize = relFontsizew + 'px';
      }
    }
    
    function stopResize() {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', resize)
    }
  }
}

makeResizableDiv('.resizable')
```

```css
body,
html {
  background: black;
}
.resizable {
  background: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

.resizable .resizers{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #4286f4;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.resizable .resizers .resizer{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%; /*magic to turn square into circle*/
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid #4286f4;
  position: absolute;
}

.resizable .resizers .resizer.top-left {
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  cursor: nwse-resize; /*resizer cursor*/
}
.resizable .resizers .resizer.top-right {
  right: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  cursor: nesw-resize;
}
.resizable .resizers .resizer.bottom-left {
  left: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  cursor: nesw-resize;
}
.resizable .resizers .resizer.bottom-right {
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  cursor: nwse-resize;
}
```

```html
<div class='resizable'>
  <div class='resizers'>
    <div class='resizer top-left'></div>
    <div class='resizer top-right'></div>
    <div class='resizer bottom-left'></div>
    <div class='resizer bottom-right'></div>
    <article id="Text" style=" width:100%; font-size:22px; color:black">Any Text</article>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: hey! thanks a lot for your response! 
 when i resize it from upper right corner, the bottom left corner should not move instead it should increase height from upside for which we will have to decrease the top as much as the height has been increased, i am tried to do that but could not accomplish it.
Thanks again!

Comment: here I have created a small gif for better understanding. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wgh3GhEOhv1syk_WFmcCGp0UJUyGzS5u/view
this is what I want to accomplish.